# is it possible in javascript to create shortcuts with sequence like 123,345 instead of combo?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts, numbers

I already used some script to implement the shortcuts in my web page

but i was wondering if could be possible to associate some combination not syncronic like Ctrl+X but more like a sequence typing 1..2..3 or any other combination to execute a script...

lets assume this example:

you have a long list with numbers:

you could type 3..5...6, so you can go to the item 356 passing trough the item 3 then 35 then 356

more or less like when you type while selecting a select box

i hope it was clear, id not easy to explain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a great script to register keystrokes sequence
that is

http://boedesign.com/demos/keystrokes/

the only problem with this script is that in case you type

'man' or 'manner', it fires on 'man' because it she shortest sequence... this script maybe needs a timer...

i'm thinking also that the solution of this problem could be in a complete different approach
using an autocomplete script on a invisible input field... what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Recommendation: create a text input, then hook the onchange event.  When the value in the box changes, navigate internally to the appropriate place on the page.  Use CSS `position:fixed` to keep the input in the right place.

example page html:

```
<p id="3">
    This is paragraph 3.
</p>
...
<p id="35">
    This is paragraph 35.
</p>
...
<p id="356">
    This is paragraph 356
</p>
```

example html for navigation box:

```
<div class="navigate">
    <p>Go to: <input type="text" id="navbox" /></p>
</div>
```

css to put it in the upper-right corner of the screen:

```
.navigate {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

javascript to perform navigation:

```
(function(){
    var navbox = document.getElementById("navbox");
    navbox.onchange = function(){
        var value = navbox.value;
        if (document.getElementById(value)) {
            window.location.assign("#" + value);
        }
    };
})();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question.  **This shouldn't be too hard**.  I'd recommend using a library like JQuery and subscribe to the **keydown even on the browser window**. Then have a buffer of the 5 most recently pressed keys, after every keypress **see if the 3 most recently pressed keys match** any saved sequence.  You could also *easily* time-stamp each keydown event and require all keys to be pressed within a certain time frame of each other to trigger the shortcut.

Comment: yep, i think this is the answer i was looking for (ropstah as well)... i didnt find anything out there os i might consider building the script...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many javascript frameworks that allow you to do that. For example, check this [JQuery autocomplete demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might like this one, where 'typeahead' is finding place..

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/autocomplete.htm

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 'keyboard shortcuts': [this](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/) is a nice script which handles shortcuts, however NOT sequences (modifiers like CTRL, SHIFT do work).

If you want a sequence of key input to be handled as 'one shortcut', I think you need to write yourself a custom script. Current libraries are not supporting this.

You need to fetch all inputs within a short amount of time (reset after every keydown). When the timer ends you validate the key-sequence which was inputted against your list of shortcuts.

Comment: yep, i think this is the answer i was looking for... i didnt find anything out there os i might consider building the script...